# Iteration not working in array for PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I have this basic query that shows which user has access to what page.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT UserName FROM tblUsers WHERE PageOne = 1") or die (mysql_error());
```

Essentially, this is checking from all the users that have access to PageOne.

I'm trying to compare if **$currentUser = $_SESSION['username']** (which correctly displays the user that is loggedin) is this person.

And after getting all the users,

I make this simple loop to check if they have access.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    if (in_array($currentUser,$row["UserName"]))
       echo "you have access"; //for testing purposes
    else
        die("you're not authorized");
}
```

this will always go into the else statement, when it shouldn't. If I try to debug this, I figured out that in the query, there should be three users, but **$row["UserName"]** only returns one user (the first one).

However, if I get rid of the if/else statements and simply print $row["UserName"], it prints the correct users.

So, how would I work around this?

Thank You!

Edit

In the while loop, if I run echo **$row["UserName"]**, I get User1User2User3 (where User3 is the CurrentUser)

To debug, I run

```
if ($currentUser == $row["UserName"])
    echo "you have access";
else
    echo $row["UserName"];
```

and I get

**User1User2you have access**

Comment: Simple question, but is `$row["UserName"]` an array ? While loop should loops 3 times for the 3 users, and you should  compare with  `if ($currentUser == $row["UserName"])`

Comment: oh the in_array was added last minute. I just used "==" to compare them actually. Is there any other way I could do this? I tried using array_values but that didn't work either.

Comment: But is $currentUser a string? If it is, the == must work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each loop of the while it takes a value of the query result. In addition, if you die when the element is not equals to the current user, it will die every time unless the $currentUser is the first element of the $row[]  So the if should be:

```
 public function checkUserInTable($tableNumber){

         $query = mysql_query("SELECT UserName FROM tblUsers WHERE PageOne = ".$tableNumber."") or die (mysql_error());

         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
              if($currentUser == $row["UserName"]){ 
                   echo "you have access"; 
                   return true; 
              } 
         } 

         return false; 
    }
```

The function call:

```
if(checkUserInTable(1))
    echo "User Accepted";
else
    die("Error Message");
```

Comment: oddly, this doesn't work...it seems like it still goes into the else statement, even though my PageOne is set to 1 for the currentUser.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But how would I reject a user if I can't access the row. If I just put the die outside, it will reject no matter what.  :( thanks

Comment: If you put it in a function and return if you found the user, it will never arrive to the die() if the user currently exist. If the user doesen't exist, then it finish the while loop and it executes the die(). Try it :)

Comment: Sorry for keep bothering you but when I tried it, it keeps going to die, even when it shouldn't. The reason is, if I echo inside the if statement, it still only gets the first element of the row. Thank you!

Comment: But in the question you say that you have:

User1User2you have access

So you iterate the row, you check the value, and you only die when you know that the current user is non of the 3 you have in the table

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted will only work if the first row returned happens to match the current user. The loop terminates otherwise. You probably want something more like this:

```
$has_access = false;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    if ($currentUser==$row["UserName"])
    {
        $has_access = true;
        break;
    }
}
// check $has_access here ...
```

However, if I were doing this, I would move the entire check into your SQL query and get rid of the loop completely (untested):

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT UserName FROM tblUsers WHERE PageOne = 1 AND UserName = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($currentUser));
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$has_access = mysql_num_rows($result) > 0;
// check $has_access
```

Comment: So I tried running the entire query, and checking if it's true and false, but the query returns nothing, and I can't figure out why, because when I test it in WorkBench it works fine.

Comment: Sorry,  I should have been more clear. What you probably want is something like:

$query = mysql_query("SELECT UserName FROM tblUsers WHERE PageOne = 1 AND UserName='".mysql_real_escape_string($currentUser)."'") or die (mysql_error());

Comment: the query works in MySQL Workbench but not when I try to run it in my code. mysql_real_escape_string($currentUser) does return the correct string so I'm not sure why the query doesn't print anything..

Answer (score 2):

Not the way to solve the problem.

Firstly, it looks as if your database schema is not normalized - users are one entity, pages are a different entity, who has access to what pages should be defined in a third table (decomposing a N:M relationship).

> I'm trying to compare if $currentUser = $_SESSION['username']

Why fetch every row of data to find out if the current user has access:

```
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(username) 
FROM tblUsers 
WHERE PageOne = 1 and username='" 
. mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])
. "'");
```

Bear in mind that you should also be re-implementing your code using a non-deprecated API. Hence it really should be:

```
$qry=mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(username) as allowed_match
FROM users u
INNER JOIN permissions p
ON u.id=p.user_id 
WHERE p.page='PageOne'
and p.allowed = 1 
and u.username='" 
. mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])
. "'");
```